# Proving the curvature of a plane curve is equal to that of a space curve

Tags: curves, parametric, plane-curves, arc-length

> Let $\gamma : (a,b) \rightarrow \mathbb{R}^2$ be a regular curve. Let $\iota : \mathbb{R}^2 \rightarrow \mathbb{R}^3$ be the map
> \begin{equation}\iota\left(\begin{pmatrix}x \\y\end{pmatrix}\right) = \begin{pmatrix}x\\y\\0\end{pmatrix}.\end{equation} Then, $(\iota \circ \gamma)$ is also a regular curve. Prove that the curvature of $\gamma$ is the same as that of $(\iota \circ \gamma)$.

It is clear to me that the curvature of these two curves are equal, but I'm struggling to prove this...

So, if we let $\gamma(t) = \begin{pmatrix}x(t)\\y(t)\end{pmatrix}$, then $(\iota \circ \gamma)(t) = \begin{pmatrix}x(t)\\y(t)\\0\end{pmatrix}$. And so, using the formula for the curvature of space curves we get that the curvature of $(\iota \circ \gamma)$ is given by
\begin{equation}
\kappa_{\iota \circ \gamma} = \frac{\lVert \ddot{\gamma} \times \dot{\gamma}\rVert}{\lVert \dot{\gamma} \rVert^3} = \frac{\ddot{x}\dot{y}-\dot{x}\ddot{y}}{(\dot{x}^2 + \dot{y}^2)^{3/2}}.
\end{equation}
But then, the curvature of $\gamma$, using the formula for the curvature of a unit-speed plane curve, is given by
\begin{equation}
\lVert \tilde{\gamma}''(s)\rVert = \sqrt{\frac{d}{dt}\left[\gamma(t(s))\right]} = \sqrt{\gamma^{''}(t(s))t^{'}(s)^2 + \gamma^{'}(t(s))t^{''}(s)} = ....
\end{equation}

Where $\tilde{\gamma}(s)$ is an arc-length reparameterisation of $\gamma$. I'm really struggling with showing that these are equal, I'm getting lost in the derivatives.

Comment: The curvature of a space curve is $\kappa=\frac{\sqrt{\bigl(z''y'-y''z'\bigr)\vphantom{'}^2+\bigl(x''z'-z''x'\bigr)\vphantom{'}^2+\bigl(y''x'-x''y'\bigr)\vphantom{'}^2}}
  {\bigl({x'}^2+{y'}^2+{z'}^2\bigr)\vphantom{'}^{3/2}}$ so you just use that $z=z'=z''=0$ and it reduces to the two dimensional case immediately.

Comment: @CyclotomicField  I think perhaps you have misunderstood what I am trying to do. I have no issue finding the curvature of the space curve. I need to prove this fact using the definitions I have stated, so I need to go from $\lVert \tilde{\gamma}(s)\rVert$ to the formula you quote, or vice versa. I.e., the definition you give does not simply reduce to the definition of curvature for a plane curve.

Comment: If you have no problem finding the curvature of $\iota \circ \gamma$  then simply find it. You'll see that it's exactly the same as the curvature of $\gamma$. Note that $\kappa_{\iota \circ \gamma} = \frac{\|\ddot{x}\dot{y}-\dot{x}\ddot{y}\|}{(\dot{x}^2 + \dot{y}^2)^{3/2}}$ is not true in general and only follows from the fact that $z=\dot{z}=\ddot{z}=0$.

Comment: Your formula for curvature of $\gamma$ is riddled with errors (both middle and rh side). Look it up again and copy it carefully. You also might want to consider that $\frac{dt}{ds} = \dfrac{1}{\frac{ds}{dt}}$